# Roslyn Analyzer Refresh in VS "14" CTP 3

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn

I have a project "A" that references the output of an "Diagnostic Analyzer" library project. 
Once the analyzer is added to project "A" the analyzer is listed under the "Analyzers" node and the rules in it get displayed. Any changes that I make in my "Diagnostic Analyzer" library are not refreshed. The only way that I get the analyzer to refresh is by closing and re-opening visual studio. Both projects are in the same solution.

Is there a setting or something that I have to do to ensure the analyzers get refreshed after "Diagnostic Analyzer" project builds?

Comment: You should post this at https://github.com/aspnet/Home as issue.

Comment: @Fals: No; at https://roslyn.codeplex.com/

Comment: got an answer here from the roslyn team https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/562257 Also found a workaround.

Comment: @Mauricio: could you describe your workaround in an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a workaround to the aforementioned issue, it is not pretty but so far it has been working for me. I created a NuGet package for the "Analyzer" library and publish to a local feed. I have the version number of the package update during build. So I added the package to project "A" and I manually uninstall the package and install it again. I tried the update-package command with the re-install option and that did not seem to work. Only uninstalling and installing again works for me at the moment.

Comment: Isn't this even more complicated than your first work-around, simply closing and reopening Visual Studio?